# Restful webservice Serlvlet init exception - Status 500

Tags: java, rest, soapui

I've deployed a web service but I'm getting an error trying to access it. I've been googling for a solution but without any success. This is a part of the response I'm getting:

```
  <p>
     <b>description</b>
     The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
  </p>
  <p>
     <b>exception</b>
     <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.restfulpractice.facade.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception</pre>
  </p>
  <p>
     <b>root cause</b>
     <pre>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when configuring to use the EJB interceptor binding API. JAX-RS EJB integration can not be supported.</pre>
  </p>
  <p>
     <b>root cause</b>
     <pre>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</pre>
  </p>
  <p>
     <b>root cause</b>
     <pre>java.lang.NullPointerException</pre>
  </p>
```

First solution I found was that I should map the class that extends Application to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restfulpractice.facade.service.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/webresources</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but I get this error from server:

SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

This is the project structure:

[image]

I'm using SOAP UI to test my web service. The service works when I access it through localhost but I'm getting above error message when trying to access it using my public ip. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have jersey-server.jar in your classpth

Comment: Ok. What will the application url be if the @ApplicationPath("webresources") considering I have a url-pattern in web.xml aswell ?